# Probability of collision for two realizations of a uniformly distributed random variable.

Tags: probability, random-variables

#### Problem

Assume the uniform discrete random variable `X` with `n` values in `E = {1,2,..,n}`. A collision occurs if two independent realizations result in the same value. Let `P(C)` denote this **collision probability**.

#### Questions

- What is the probability of a collision? What is the probability of a collision as a function of the distribution of `X`?

#### My Thoughts

From what I understand, `X` takes inputs from a sample space at random and maps them to a value in `E`. To find the probability of a collision - in other words, that two different inputs from the sample space map to the same value in `E` - I make following assumptions.

- assume a random input is picked and `X` maps it to some `x` in `E`
- assume another random input is picked. The probability that `X` also maps this to the same `x` in `E` is `1/n`, as `X` is uniform.

I am pretty new to this stuff and any input would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Correct reasoning. The probability on a collision is $\frac1n$.

Answer (score 1):

In general if $X$ has discrete probability distribution taking values on some countable set $S$ then the probability on a collision is:$$P(\mathsf C)=\sum_{s\in S}P(X=s,Y=s)=\sum_{s\in S}P(X=s)P(Y=s)=\sum_{s\in S}p(s)^2$$where $p$ denotes the probability mass function of $X$ and the second equality exploits independence.

Applying that here we find: $$P(\mathsf C)=\sum_{s=1}^n\frac1{n^2}=n\cdot\frac1{n^2}=\frac1n$$ for the probability of a collision.

The way you handled it yourself is more direct and more elegant but is not fruitful if the distribution is not uniform.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and clarification!